# How to change the text of the last clicked button in tkinter python

Tags: python, button, text, tkinter

I have dynamically created a buttons by looping through a list:

```
AuxName = Button(GUI_1, text=List_Aux[x], font=("Arial", 10))
tk_rgb = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (0,0,0)
AuxName["fg"] = tk_rgb
tk_rgb = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (255,255,255)
AuxName["bg"] = tk_rgb
AuxName.place(x=BUTTON_LEFT_AUX1, y=BUTTON_TOP_AUX1 , height=BUTTON_HEIGTH_AUX1, width=BUTTON_WIDTH_AUX1)
AuxName["command"] = ButtonClick
```

Each button has a different AuxName value (1btn1, 1btn2, 1btn3, etc) numbers being the column and the row where each button is located.

The problem I'm having is that now I want the function `ButtonClick` to get the name of the button being clicked.
The last thing I tried was:

```
def ButtonClick():
1btn1["text"] = "Goodbye"
```

But python throws a syntax error (and points just before the opening bracket).

How could I get the last clicked button name, and then change its text through the function `ButtonClick()`?

-------------------- Edit to the first answer, almost working perfectly now ------------

Thank you for the answer, I appreciate it very much, and makes it work almost perfect.
There are two flaws, first of them is it will throw an error because of the command ButtonClick being sent with no argument, which is the default way to send commands of the button binds, so I dont really know how to fix that...
And the second is, after using the code you provided me, buttons text will change as you especified, but they wont respect the position and size previously defined by me.

```
BUTTON_TOP_AUX1 = 20
BUTTON_WIDTH_AUX1 = 400
BUTTON_LEFT_AUX1 = 5
BUTTON_HEIGTH_AUX1 = 20
Buttons_Function = "DesiredFunctionOne"
BUTTON_COLUMN_AUX1 = 1
List_Size_Aux = len(List_Aux)
for x in range ( List_Size_Aux ):
    AuxName = str(BUTTON_COLUMN_AUX1)+'btn'+str(x)
    AuxName = Button(GUI_1, text=List_Aux[x], font=("Arial", 10))
    tk_rgb = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (0,0,0)
    AuxName["fg"] = tk_rgb
    tk_rgb = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (255,255,255)
    AuxName["bg"] = tk_rgb
    AuxName.place(x=BUTTON_LEFT_AUX1, y=BUTTON_TOP_AUX1 , height=BUTTON_HEIGTH_AUX1, width=BUTTON_WIDTH_AUX1)
    AuxName["command"] = ButtonClick
    BUTTON_TOP_AUX1 = BUTTON_HEIGTH_AUX1+BUTTON_TOP_AUX1
    AuxName.bind("<Button-1>", ButtonClick)
    AuxName.pack()
```

Could you please tell me how to fix those?
Greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Edited the question on current status, thank you

Comment: I have updated the answer with a more detailed solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to bind the function to an event, instead of using the `command` attribute. For a left click on a widget, remove the line

And use the event `<Button-1>` instead:

```
AuxName.bind("<Button-1>", ButtonClick)
```

Then in the event handler you receive an event argument. It has a `widget` field, so you can get the widget which triggered the event:

```
def ButtonClick(event):
    event.widget['text'] = 'Goodbye'
```

Remembar that you have to remove the `AuxName['command'] = ButtonClick`, because if you don't do so, `ButtonClick` will be executed two times (one of them without any argument).

When you change the text of the Button, it will modify also its width since the new text may have a different lenght. One problem you have in respect to the position of the widgets is that you are using both `place` and `pack` as geometry managers:

```
AuxName.place(...)
# ...
AuxName.pack()
```

In Tkinter, you should use consistently one geometry manager. In this case, I suggest you to use the [grid geometry manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), which is the easiest to use:

```
AuxName.grid(row=x, column=y, ...)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, everything working great now, and I learned a lot from your answers :)

Comment: @user2138906 You're welcome, feel free to accept the answer to help other know this solved your problem ;)